# Catalog Price Rules - Apply Rule - Fatal Error Max Time

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, catalog-price-rules

I hope everyone is well. I have a problem with my Magento e-commerce, and I am trying to explain this in the most technical way possible (even though I am not an expert). I looked at other messages on StackExchange, but could not find anything.

Every time I try to apply a new Catalog Price Rules, and I have already more than 4 rules set, then, I receive a

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/deltoro/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 289
```

It labels my rule as 'Active' , but it's not.

If I turn it 'Inactive' and apply the rule, then it updates without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error because of Maximum execution time is exceeded

looking for php.ini file in my case file location is

```
C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

open php.ini and find for

**max_execution_time**

and change value to 3000 to 30000 (or as par requirement )

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Place this at the top of your PHP script or Index.php in your root directory

Taken from [Increase PHP Script Execution Time Limit Using ini_set()](http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-script-execution-time-limit-ini_set)